# How can I restrict my url only accept linked-n link as an input

Tags: javascript, html

I make a user profile where user only can add LinkedIn URL

I tried

```
pattern="^http(s)?:\/\/(www)?\.linkedin\.com\/in\/.*$";
```

regular expression in html but it restrict any thing. I also added in js that user-linkedin only except linked-in link. but if I put `abc_name` it will show

```
https://www.linkedin.com/in/abcname
```

but if I put `https://www.google.com` then it exact show the url.

html:

```
<input type="text" class="user-linkedin" id="user-linkedin" placeholder="LinkedIn Profile ID">
```

js:

```
userDetails.linkedin = 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/' + userDetails.linkedin.replace('http://www.linkedin.com/in/', '').replace('https://www.linkedin.com/in/','');

$(subpage.selector + ' .user-linkedin').val(userDetails.linkedin);
$(subpage.selector + ' .linkedin-link').attr('href',userDetails.linkedin);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your requirements correctly and you need a regex to match only linked in profile link, the following one should meet your demand:

```
^http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?linkedin\.com\/in\/.*$
```

```html
<form>
  <input pattern="^http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?linkedin\.com\/in\/.*$" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

If you need to check that the input is a valid link and insert it somewhere in DOM using Jquery, you can do that as follows:

```js
$(".user-linkedin").on('input', function(event) {
  var validLink = /^http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?linkedin\.com\/in\/.*$/.test(event.target.value)
    ? event.target.value
    : '';
  $(".linkedin-link")
    .text(validLink || 'invalid link')
    .attr("href", validLink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="user-linkedin" />
<br>
Link: <a href="" class="linkedin-link"></a>
```

Comment: I add this regex as patteern="/^http(s)?:\/\/(www)?\.linkedin\.com\/in\/.*$/"  in html. But still didn't work.

Comment: Try to remove leading and trailing slashes, I have updated the answer with the demo. 

I have added the slashes in first place assuming that the regex is to be used in JavaScript, but in an input attribute they should not be specified.

Comment: I try this code. But didn't work for my code. Is there something i'm missing in java script?

Comment: I have added a Jquery example to the answer, hope it may be of some help

Comment: this part `(www)?\.linkedin` should be `(www\.)?linkedin`

Comment: @ArleighHix You are right, thanks, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @antonku . But i really need modify in javascript. I tried your code in my project. But it didn't work.

Comment: been helpful save lot of time